# Remove duplicate data from loop php

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to output 3 text fields with these values:

- 100
- 200
- 300

But however I get duplicate output:

> 100,200,300
>   100,200,300
>   100,200,300

I have used `array_unique` function, but its not working.

```
$items = ["Maids","Housekeepers","Nannies"];
foreach ( array_unique($items) as $item ) {

    $retArr = ["100", "200", "300"];
    foreach (array_unique($retArr) as $jobopening) {?>

        <input value="<?php echo $jobopening; ?>" type="text" />

    <?php }

}?>
```

Can someone please help me to achieve this output:

> 100,200,300

Comment: You are outputting each element of `$retArr` once for each element of `$items` - why do you have both loops ?

Comment: I have it for a reason, it is just a sample code, i want to achieve this inside the nested loop, thanks

Comment: what is use of `$item` ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: that is just a sample code, i'm using it for other purpose

Comment: expected output is text field 100,200,300 but right now im getting duplicate output 100,200,300 100,200,300 100,200,300

Comment: Its because of there is loop inside loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know your exact requirement but you can try this:

```
    <?php

    $items = ["Maids","Housekeepers","Nannies"];
    $i=0;
    foreach ( array_unique($items) as $item ) {

    $retArr = array_unique(["100", "200", "300"]); ?>

        <input value="<?php echo $retArr[$i]; ?>" type="text" />

    <?php $i++; }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the `$retArr` variable values inside the `<input> text` box according to the `$items` loop.

Please see the below code:

```
<?php
$x = 0;
$items = ["Maids","Housekeepers","Nannies"];
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $retArr = ["100", "200", "300"]; ?>
        <input value="<?php echo $retArr[$x]; ?>" type="text" />
    <?php
    $x++;
}

?>
```

There is no need of `array_unique` function, in case you really have duplicate values.

I hope, it may be helpful to you.